# what's exactly happening in getView

Tags: android

I see this a lot in Adapter extensions override of getView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.whatever, null);
        }
```

I get semantically what's happening - "if convertView is null then inflate it", but I don't really understand why - what circumstance would convertView be null, and in what circumstance would it already be a View?

Also (and I know "1 question per post"), *but as it relates to the above* - what's exactly happens during the inflate method?  I know what it does generally ("inflates" a view resource to be parsed and populated), but don't fully grok it...

TYIA

Comment: Adapter is used by AdapterView ... some implementation of AdapterView (AbsListView and other) using getView to ... well ... get View, for Adapter item ... there is a lot of optimization in this implemetations ... so AbsListView(and other) will not create new view but rather reuse unused ... what i mean but "unused" ... i ll try to show you on example ... ListView should have about 100 elements ... but only 5 of them are visible at one time so ListView will call fx getView with convertView == null for about 7 times and then will try to point unused one as convertView ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your list adapter has 1000 objects. Each object is represented by a view. On the phone screen there's place only for maybe some 10 such views. You scroll the list wanting to see more items. Some items go out of sight because you're scrolling. It makes no sense for the Framework to create more views as they will be exactly the same as those which have just gone out of sight. Framework thus can reuse some views it created before and so it offers to you such a possibility by offering you a non-null `convertView`.

During the inflate method a View object gets created out of some XML resource. The XML resource has a description of a View  sufficient for that View to be created and so the `inflate` method does that creation. So no view - you create a new one by inflating, there is a view already - you can reuse it (you don't have to but you should)

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK, this is how getView works.

Suppose you have a list with 50 items and you can only see 5 items at a time. The getView will be called 5 times initially and the convertView will be null for each row and a new row should be inflated.

As you scroll through the list the getView will be called again as the next rows get visible on the screen. Now since 5 rows are already rendered for the list, these rows will be recycled by updating existing rows with new values to show new rows. At this case the convertView will not be null.

Comment: +1 for good, clear answer...  i gave the accept to Alex since he covered both questions... and he can use the points more than you can :)

Comment: Surely Blessenm's answer is much more clear and precise - with this I wholeheartedly agree. I've upvoted for this answer, too, and if this answer could be accepted instead of imprecise mine that would be real great.

Answer (score 2):

for full information i recommend you to watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) 
it will tell you alot of information include what is happening in `getView()`