# passing row data from adapter to new Activity from ListView

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListView which is created with SimpleCursorAdapter.
The list represents merchants. When someone clicks on a merchant i want to view full details of this particular merchant.

on this list (lv1) im setting a listener

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {

            //Cursor merchant = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(pos);

            Intent merchant = new Intent(v.getContext(), MerchantView.class);
            merchant.putExtra("merchantPosition", pos);
            startActivity(merchant);
        }
    });
```

1. How should I pass the data to merchant view in most optimal way?
2. I have static reference to adapter so I guess I could use somehow getItem call (just as in commented out line) and then pass it as putExtra to Merchant. If that is the way to do it how should I use getItem (I tried couple of times but failed to extract data that i want).

P.S Adapter is making sql query earlier to database with columns - ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,STATUS

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in my Apps, is override the `SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder()` to set the Tag of Views inside the ListView with the ID from the DB and pass this ID to the intent in the `setOnItemClickListener()`. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384088/simplecursoradapter-and-viewbinder-binding-data-to-listview-items-to-be-retrie/8384392#8384392) which is a similar case to what you want to do